# Why do the values of x and y not decrement in this code?

Tags: c, if-statement, decrement

I have been trying to figure out why the output of the code below is 2 2 but can't seem to figure out why. I get that the else statement is getting executed but from what I've read I can't understand why the first print doesn't get executed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 1, y = 1;

    if(x++ == y++)
        printf("%d%d", x--, y--);
    else
        printf("%d%d", x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

Originally I expected the output to be 0 0

I have played around with changing the values and the operators and each time the decrement print never executed. From what I can tell from reading on the topic decrementing inside a print should be possible but I'm not sure what is making it not execute.

Comment: This is called undefined behavior

Comment: No, @DanielA.White, it isn't.

Comment: 2 2 is the output I would expect.

Comment: In `x--, y--` the values of x and y are used BEFORE *post-decrement*

Comment: Remove the `else`

Comment: You cannot tell from the output which branch is taken, because the same output will be produced either way.

Comment: There's nothing special with this example, it calculates 1 + 1 and then prints it. Also when you can't figure out why the first printf doesn't get executed, maybe do some common sense debugging: `printf("FIRST %d%d", x--, y--); else printf("SECOND %d%d", x,y);` Since it prints `FIRST 2 2`, well there you go. Otherwise you could also have single stepped through this with your favourite debugger.

Comment: As for if there is anything to learn from this... Yes, namely: _avoid mixing `++` with other operators in the same expression_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if` block *is* being executed.

In the condition `if(x++ == y++)`, the current value of `x` is compared with the current value of `y`.  Both are 1 so the comparison is true, and both `x` and `y` are incremented as a side effect.

So then this statement runs:

```
printf("%d%d", x--, y--);
```

Which prints the current values of `x` and `y` which are both 2, and both are decremented as a side effect.  If you were to print both after this, you would see that both are 1.

Answer (score 2):

In order to understand your code, you might do the following:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 1, y = 1;

    printf("x=%d, y=%d", x,y);
    if(x++ == y++)
    {
        printf("x=%d, y=%d", x,y);
        printf("x--=%d, y--=%d", x--, y--);
        printf("x=%d, y=%d", x,y);
    }
    else
        printf("x=%d, y=%d", x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()

{
   int x = 1, y = 1;

   if(x++ == y++)               // here x and y become 2
    printf("%d%d", x--, y--);   // x with postfix decrement x and
                                //  returns the initial value 
   else
    printf("%d%d", x,y);
  return 0;
}
```

lot of help You get
my recomendation use prefix `++x`

Comment: Why would using the prefix increments alter things?  The comparison would compare `2` vs `2` whereas the original (postfix increments) compares `1` vs `1`, but it's not clear that matters.

Comment: [learncpp](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/increment-decrement-operators-and-side-effects/) I guess this could help you to understand difference post-- and pre-- . and sorry about error, yes you are right that is decrement, fixed it